# Is there a meteor.js library available for managing user accounts?

Tags: node.js, meteor, user-management, account-management

Is there a meteor.js library available for managing user accounts?

I'd like to have users register, have access to unique user IDs to limit the number of times a single user can do something, and also have different tiers of users to control access.  It would be great if I didn't have to build this out myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at the [accounts api](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_api), and the [passwords package](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_passwords), which should save you writing most of the boilerplate code for implementing user accounts.

There is also the [accounts-ui package](http://docs.meteor.com/#accountsui) with support for facebook, google, and others.

You'll need to implement your own ACL and make sure collections have appropriate permissions.

Finally have a look at the [All Tomorrow's Parties](http://meteor.com/examples/parties) demo for some sample implementation.

Comment: Do you know where I can find documentation specifically related to accounts-google?  When I try to use it with accounts-ui I'm getting an error about a Google key, but I'm not sure what to do about it.  So far my searches for anything about accounts-google has turned up nothing.

Comment: @Matt, sorry for the late reply. I think you'll need to setup your oAuth tokens from Google and then configure the Meteor app. The Meteor docs state that you can follow "step-by-step guides" from the accounts-ui package, perhaps when you install the package there is a prompt? Check out the "login with external service" docs for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Shameless plug: Here's an account manager based on the Meteor Roles package -

https://github.com/hharnisc/meteor-accounts-admin-ui-bootstrap-3/

Tutorials included in the readme.